# Creating a better mesh

Tags: pcl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wanted to create mesh of household objects, so that I can later recreate the household scene in Gazebo. I want to use kinect and think that interactively, it can be done quite easily. My exact problem:

After capturing the scene using kinect, I am able to filter out chair, the front view of the chair looks: [image: image description]

However when I am trying to create a mesh from it (using PCL, tutorial at: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php#greedy-triangulation I am not able to set optimal size of triangles. My mesh looks like:
[image: image description]

I need a smooth mesh. As if a low pass filter is passed on it. How can I achieve that.

Any help or pointer is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/178901/creating-a-better-mesh/) by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2014-06-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found that this could be easily done using MLS (moving-least-squares).

The tutorial given at: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php#moving-least-squares helps in generating smooth mesh.

However when I try to combine it with mesh generation code in one go, I got segmentation fault. Any help there is greatly appreciated. I have asked it at: http://answers.ros.org/question/187188/unable-to-combine-mls-and-mesh-generation-in-one-file/

---

Originally posted by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) with karma: 339 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1